# Putting a smaller circle into a bigger one and uniting them with a rectangle without the inner circle disappearing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So basically I have 2 circles. A smaller one inside a bigger one. Kinda like a tire. But the problem is, when I group and then unite them with a rectangle, the inner circle disappears instead of uniting. How do I change that?

Comment: Can you please include an image in your question - perhaps showing what you have tried, and what result you are looking for. It's very difficult to answer such questions blind.

Answer (score 2):

Uniting a shape with another when the bigger one totally covers the smaller one, the smaller one disappears totally.

Unite is intended to combine shapes to one when the shapes cover each other only partially or not at all.

Unite means the same as union in the set theory.

If you want to keep the smaller circle you can add it after uniting the bigger circle with something. If you want a hole, subtract the smaller circle from the bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what you're doing but, you can copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the inner circle, then do what you're doing then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and you'll get a new inner circle in the same position.